# Hidden menu after click on links - HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I'm trying to make a hidden responsive menu after clicking on links. When I click on the first link it's working but when I click on another link menu doesn't disappear. I was also tried nava = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links a'); but then menu didn't close even after clicking on the first link.

```html
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.nav_links_menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');
    const nava = document.querySelector('.nav_links a');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    })

    nava.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    })
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.nav_links a');` This will only select the first link inside the `nav_links` container. All other links don't have the event listener. You'll need to use `querySelectorAll` and loop through them or make sure you specifically select the link(s) you want to work with the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind all  tags. And you already tried that:

`nava = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links a'`.

Then you have iterate every element of this collection and add event listener like that:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.nav_links_menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');
    const nava = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links a');

    nava.forEach(n => {
      n.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
      })  
    })
    
}

navSlide();
```

```css
.nav_active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_links_menu">
  <div class="nav_links">
    <a href="nav_active">1</a>
    <a href="">2</a>
    <a href="">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explain and learn me something new.